Keep pytorch with CUDA in pip cache
I frequently need to install torch with CUDA in different virtual environments. Conda is not a good option for various reasons, so I need to install via pip. I do this following the instructions from https://pytorch.org/
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121

This leads to a 2.5GB download which is fine once, but gets exhausting quickly. To my understanding, pip should by default cache downloads (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/caching/).
However, using the command above, torch does not land in the cache; if I reinstall in another venv, it redownloads torch, and if I check with pip cache list, torch is not there.
I tried creating environment variables like PIP_DOWNLOAD_CACHE or PIP_FIND_LINKS, as suggested in some other topics, but those don't seem to help either.
Also, I figured that the --index-url parameter might prohibit using the cache. However, if I pip install torch without --index-url, it just downloads a different version.
Python version is 3.10, pip 23.0.1. Any advice?

As usual, asking the question is sufficient to find the solution.
Upgrading to pip-24.0 with
 python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

is sufficient, now the cache is recognised.
